# Sharing Wishlist on google play store

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to share or transfer wishlist from one account to another on google play store?

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2012, this is not supported. From [TabletPCReview](http://www.tabletpcreview.com/default.asp?newsID=3570&news=Google%20Play%20Store%20Wish%20Lists):

> The function only serves as a bookmark currently, meaning users can't
>   share their list with others as "subtle" hints of future gifts.

There doesn't seem to be any app in Google Play that deals with the wishlist either. Perhaps the API for this is closed.